# OLAP Error while Processing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas, olap, cube

I am new to OLAP, and figured out how to make a cube and process it. However, when i play with it too much, i eventually come up against this error:

> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The
>   attribute key cannot be found: Table:
>   dbo_v_MYEntities, Column: uniqueId,
>   Value: 2548. Errors in the OLAP
>   storage engine: The record was skipped
>   because the attribute key was not
>   found. Attribute: Unique Id of
>   Dimension: v MY Entities from
>   Database: Test Cube New, Cube: MYdm
>   MyApp - Views, Measure Group: v MY
>   Entities, Partition: v MY Entities,
>   Record: 2526.

It seems that some values get stuck, and the cube expect the value to be there, I know i can edit error properties and stop it from throwing exceptions, but i would like to be able to fix it.

I wouldn't mind clearing the cube, so that it re-generates itself from scratch, but i can't seem to be able to do that.

Once i get this error, even if i delete the cube, and create it again from scratch, the error is still there.

The only solution so far (in my test environment) was to change database name in project deployment target properties. Obviously this will not do the trick in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically,

> Table: dbo_v_MYEntities, Column:
>   uniqueId, Value: 2548

Means that your table/view "dbo.v_MYEntities" has a column "uniqueid", which contains a value "2548" which is not in a table which is related to dbo.v_MYEntities in the dimension usage tab in BIDS. This usually happens when dbo.v_MYEntities is a fact table, and the related dimension table does not contain a key. I would check the referential integrity of the schema trying to determine why this is happening and correct it in the ETL or in the view definition.